Getting Html.DisplayFor() to ignore my display template for one column
I have the following column defined in one of my database entities.
[DisplayName("Rate per UOM")]
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(19,8)")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.######}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public double RatePerUom { get; set; }

And then I display it in a table like this.
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => rate.RatePerUom)</td>

But this rounds the value to two decimal places. The reason for this is that I have a display template for the Double type that limits the number of decimal places to 2, which is what I want in most cases.
Is there a way to tell Html.DisplayFor() that it should ignore the display template and instead use my display format for this column?
I realize I can just not use Html.DisplayFor(), but then we will still see this issue if another developer uses it somewhere else.
Note: I tried using:
[UIHint("None")]

But this had no effect.

You can address this issue by creating a custom display template or directly formatting the output in your view, each method depending on how frequently you need specific formatting for double values.
